# What's the default root bash prompt?

Tags: bash, command-prompt

In my case, the root bash prompt is

```bash
[hostname dir]# (in color red)
```

Where can I find the default bash prompt for the root user in my linux system? 
I just found default *plain* user bash prompt in `etc/skel/.bashrc`

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit based on OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969506/whats-the-default-root-bash-prompt/66969593?noredirect=1#comment118990382_66969593).

Looking at ArtixLinux [bash source](https://gitea.artixlinux.org/artixlinux/packages/src/branch/master/bash/x86_64/core/system.bashrc), `PS1` is set as:

```sh
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

- `\u` Username
- `\h` Hostname (short)
- `\W` Working Directory (basename)
- `\$` Prompt sign

---

If we look at the [ss64 bash syntax-prompt](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html) page, we can find:

> This change can be made permanent by placing the export PS1 definition in your ~/.bashrc file.
> To see what is currently defined in your .bashrc/.bash_profile use grep 'PS1' $HOME/.bash{rc,_profile}
>
> **The default value on many distros is `'\s-\v\$ '`**

So the default PROMT is:

- `\s`: The name of the shell, the basename of $0 (the portion following the final slash).
- `-`: Literal `-` char
- `\v`: The version of Bash (e.g., 2.00)
- `\$`: If you are not root, inserts a `$`; if you are root, you get a `#`  (root uid = 0)
- : Literal space

Comment: It does not fit my system. In my system (artixlinux) without any customization, the root has prompt `[hostname dir]` in red.

Comment: Well, you should have mentioned that in the question. You asked for the default bash prompt and that's exactly what my answer explains.

Comment: So, how can I know which file defines the root prompt of my system?

Comment: Search for it? Read the source code? Donno, but even tho it's not even in the scope of your current question, that kind of questions do not belong on SO. Rather on something like [su].

Comment: Please take a look at my edit, It seems that the default PS1 is defined [here](https://gitea.artixlinux.org/artixlinux/packages/src/branch/master/bash/x86_64/core/system.bashrc)

Comment: I found it in `/etc/bash/bashrc.d/artix.bashrc`: with color `PS1='\[\033[01;31m\][\h\[\033[01;36m\] \W\[\033[01;31m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '` without color `PS1='\u@\h \W \$ '`

Answer (score 1):

Once user logins into the system, user environment variables are initialized from various files:

```
/etc/profile or /etc/bashrc (system wide)
~/.bash_profile , ~/.bash_login , ~/.profile , ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_logout (user)
```

[gnu doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PS1)s tell more about prompt

You can customise/define your prompt temporary means for current shell session

```
export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$"
```

to make it permanent paste this line in `.bashrc`, and then `source .bashrc`

[for more customisation](http://for%20more%20customisation)

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a configuration option to enable interpretation of backslash escapes in the `PS1` string, `--enable-prompt-string-decoding`, and it's very commonly enabled.

Then, many distros come with a pre-set value of something like this, for example in Ubuntu:

```sh
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

If `PS1` isn't set, the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PS1) tells us

> The default value is `\s-\v\$` .

which looks something like `-bash-5.1$` .

We can also see that in `config-top.h` in the [source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/config-top.h#n81):

```c
#define PPROMPT "\\s-\\v\\$ "
```